# Media query doesn't work on browsers or mobile devices

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to get a simple media query working and it doesn't seem to work either in browsers (any of them) or the mobile devices. It's in the `head` tag but didn't think that mattered. I changed the `max-width` to a high number for testing. Also, I tried with and without the `viewport` meta tag.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; background:#004716; }
    p { display: inline-table; margin: 5px 5px 10px 7px; padding: 5px 5px 5px 7px; width: 30%; text-align: left; vertical-align: text-top; }
    p.filled { color: #ffffff; background: #709231; }
    p.left { margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 5px 0; width: 100%; text-align: left; }

    @media screen (max-width:760px) { p.filled { color: #000000; background: #ff9900; } }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing "and" in your rule

```
@media screen and (max-width:760px) { 
   p.filled { color: #000000; background: #ff9900; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an operator to separate the two media rules.

`and` operator or `,`(comma) for or operator. `and` will check for both conditions and `,` checks for one of the conditions to be true.

```
@media screen and (max-width:760px) {
   p.filled { 
     color: #000000; 
     background: #ff9900;  
   } 
}
```